# How to get channel name in Bot Framework

Tags: c#, botframework, bots

I am working on MS Bot Framework App.I want to know how many peoples are coming from specific channels like via webchat, DirectLine, etc. I want to maintain a log of this. How to can I get channel name from context?

Comment: For reference, are you using .NET or Node SDK for BotBuilder?

Comment: I am using .NET

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following code to get the channel type:

```
context.Activity.ChannelId
```

For example, if it is "telegram", you've gotten the message from the "telegram".

Answer (score 3):

If someone from Node.js needs this information too, channel name is stored in, as far as I know:

```
session.message.address.channelId
```

and in:

```
session.message.source
```