# Cannot display choices as Adaptive cards in Skype channel from MS Bot Rest API

Tags: botframework, bots, skype

I try to add the choices (dropdown options) from the ms bot. When I try to do the API call I cannot get the choices in the chat (Skype) which is appearing the empty adaptive card. What Rest API format should I use to implement the choices in the chat using ms bot?

Please refer to the below image showing the chat.

[image]

```
{
    "type":"message",
    "replyToId":"1546161996823",
    "conversation":
    {
        "id":"29:1nx20fU3aWIiv8P6DFhvS8GI0NRa-NlQ8ofk4i9ETyc0"

    },
    "from":
    {
        "id":"28:07807967-5b86-4184-9fae-354edd99eed9",
        "name":"incoxtest"

    },
        "recipient":
        {
            "id":"29:1nx20fU3aWIiv8P6DFhvS8GI0NRa-NlQ8ofk4i9ETyc0",
            "name":"gopal ravipillai"

        },
    "attachments": [
        {
            "contentType": "application/vnd.microsoft.card.adaptive",
            "content": {
                "type": "AdaptiveCard",
                "body": [
                    {
                        "type": "Input.ChoiceSet",
                        "id": "snooze",
                        "style": "ListStyle.List",
                        "choices": [
                            {
                                "title": "5 minutes",
                                "value": "5"
                            },
                            {
                                "title": "15 minutes",
                                "value": "15"
                            },
                            {
                                "title": "30 minutes",
                                "value": "30"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Skype channel does not support Adaptive cards. Refer the channel inspector: https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/channel-inspector/channels/Skype?f=AdaptiveCards&e=example1

One alternative is to identify the channel type and change the feature to a supported one. For eg: when the channel type is Skype instead of Adaptive cards use something that is supported by Skype like Thumbnail card. To identify the channel type refer:
[How to get channel name in Bot Framework](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44491769/how-to-get-channel-name-in-bot-framework)

Comment: Thanks, Mathew for the response. I tried the link that you gave but I didn't get the solution. Exact thing I needed which is not only for me those who are looking to provide a choice list from the ms bot definitely will helpful the **exact code sample** that how to populate the choices from the MS Bot. I also tried with the different card which are Thumbnail and HeroCard but I didn't get the output with the choices.

Comment: To summarize Tony's answer: there is no dropdown list possibility with Adaptive Cards with Skype channel. You have to use another idea: avoid using Adaptive Cards, and go to something like doing a carousel with the different values.